# Fortify high: Access specifier manipulation on reflection that is used to invoke a private constructor

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, fortify

I used reflection to invoke a private constructor of a class in order to solve insufficient branch coverage issue shown by sonar scan report. This is the snippet of my code I was working:

```
// reflection to access a private constructor of a class
        Constructor<CMISBridgeMaps> c = CMISBridgeMaps.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
        c.setAccessible(true);
        cmisBridgeMaps = c.newInstance(new Object[0]);
```

The above code solved my sonar scan critical issue. But unfortunately fortify is now showing the ***Access specifier manipulation*** issue on the following line:

```
c.setAccessible(true);
```

How can I solve both fortify and sonarcube issues? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Spring, you can use `ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field)` to make that field accessible. Fortify does not complain about this tweak.

You can read more about this in [this article](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-springs-reflectionutils-to-access-private-fields/).

Comment: It served perfectly to solve the problem proposed by the question. And that's what matters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java's reflection api to solve this. Below is the solution I used for the same issue.

```
Field field = objectToBeUpdated.getClass().getDeclaredField("paramName");
AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new AccessibleObject[] {field}, true);
```

Below are the imports for the classes used above.

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you do not need to run fortify scan on your UNIT TCs. As they are written to verify your code and they do not run into your production/actual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your application follow the below approach then you can mark  this issue as False positive .

1. Application is using reflection mechanism to access the field values dynamically by 
   reading the configurations defined in Database tables.
2. While accessing the objects, method or input field , application is using any filter.
3. Before execute the untrusted code.must apply the proper filtration process.